# Anyone use both Tortoise Git and Subversion on the same machine?

Tags: svn, git, mercurial, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

Anyone install both?  Using each for separate projects obviously.  Shouldn't be a problem, I'm guessing, but hoping to fish out any gotchas.  Furthermore, anyone use Tortoise Git, Subversion and Mercurial on the same machine?

**Edit:** Forgot to mention, this is for Windows 7.

Comment: I have had no problems using Mercurial and Subversion together.

Comment: @Steve: You mean on the same user account right? Because I can certainly install 10 different VCS on 10 different user account without ever needing the *admin/root* password and on a well conceived OS it is *impossible* for a non-root user account to mess with what's in another user account (I've got four different user accounts opened as I type this, including one only to browse the Internet ;)

Comment: @WizardOfOdds - Yes, one user account on Windows 7.  Forgot to mention that little important piece of info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got Tortoise[SVN|Git|HG] installed on my Win7 desktop, with no apparent conflicts. Apparently SVN and HG even use the same icon overlays - Git's are different.

Answer (score 3):

It should not be a problem as long as you don’t try to use them on the same files.

Answer (score 3):

TortoiseHg and TortoiseSVN [cooperate with each other](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/1.0/explorer.html#overlay-icons) when displaying the overlay icons: they both use a library called TortoiseOverlays, which is provided by the TortoiseSVN team. So it is fine to install both at the same time.

I don't know if TortoiseGit also uses the TortoiseOverlays library, but I would expect so.

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN and TortoiseHg on the same machine doesn't seem to be a problem. I don't know about TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 8.1, there is a problem with icon overlays. When you check out a new repository in hg, git puts unversioned overlays on the folders, even though the folders are versioned in hg.